# How can I merge two beautiful soup tags?

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm pulling all `<ul>` tags that occur within  body text of pages and concatenating the `<p>` tag that precedes them immediately.

```
text = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.getspokal.com/how-to-create-content-based-on-your-customers-pain-points/', timeout=7.00).text)
```

I use a function with beautiful soup to pull appropriate tags:

```
def funct(tag):
        return tag.name == 'ul' and not tag.attrs and not tag.li.attrs and not tag.a
ul_tags = text.find_all(funct)
```

This pulls three `<ul>` tags. Now find the `<p>` tag that immediately precedes each of these `<ul>` tags and concatenate:

```
combined = [(ul.find_previous("p") + ul) for ul in ul_tags]
```

This produces an error that reads

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'Tag'
```

One of the results should be this:

```
<p>For example, if you’re in the pet food industry, you might ask your existing customers:</p<ul><li>What challenges do you face on a regular basis with regards your pets?</li><li>Are there any underlying health issues that your pets have that causes you concern?</li><li>What is your biggest struggle when choosing appropriate food for your pet? </li></ul>
```

Where am I going wrong with the list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the list comprehension to this:

```
combined = [(str(ul.find_previous("p")) + str(ul)) for ul in ul_tags]
```

The problem is `ul` is not a string, it is actually a `bs4.element.Tag`, so you must convert it first.